# How to change Visual Studio version needed to compile cocos2d-x project?

Tags: visual-studio, cocos2d-x

So I am trying to compile my project using cocos command line tool with

```
cocos deploy -p win32 -m release
```

And it says

```
Required VS version : [2013, 2015, 2017]
```

I have VS2017 and VS2019 installed, and it is using VS2017. But it can't compile it, because it needs v142 build tools, and I simply can't install them to VS2017.

Is there some way to install v142 build tools to Visual Studio 2017 or make it work with Visual Studio 2019?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Gerard097 not really. I just googled some errors in cocos, fixed them locally and compiled it all in VS2019. There is no way to install v142 for VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd proj.win32\
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -AWin32
```

[more details](https://youtu.be/EPncmb5ujJo?t=898)

[doc page](https://docs.cocos.com/cocos2d-x/v4/manual/en/installation/CMake-Guide.html)